# Creating a python 2.7 conda environment sets python 3.5

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

On Ubuntu 16.04 I created an environment with this command:
`conda create -n ros2 python=2.7`

And then activated it like so: `conda activate ros2`

But then `python --version` gives "Python 3.5.2"

Why is this so? How can I set the version of python to be 2.7?

`which python` gives "/home/brads/anaconda3/envs/ros2/bin/python"

`echo $PATH` gives: "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/brads/anaconda3/envs/ros2/bin:/home/brads/anaconda3/condabin:/home/brads/bin:/home/brads/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/snap/bin"

Contents of `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin`:

```
binvox2bt                 edit_octree                     opencv_waldboost_detector  roslaunch-deps  rosservice   rqt_dep           stage
bt2vrml                   eval_octree_accuracy            rosbag                     roslaunch-logs  rossrv       rqt_graph         tf_remap
catkin_find               graph2tree                      rosboost-cfg               rosmake         rosstack     rqt_image_view    view_frames
catkin_init_workspace     log2graph                       rosclean                   rosmaster       rostest      rqt_logger_level  xacro
catkin_make               opencv_annotation               rosconsole                 rosmsg          rostopic     rqt_plot
catkin_make_isolated      opencv_createsamples            roscore                    rosmsg-proto    rosunit      rqt_shell
catkin_test_results       opencv_interactive-calibration  roscreate-pkg              rosnode         roswtf       run_selftest
catkin_topological_order  opencv_traincascade             rosgraph                   rospack         rqt          rviz
compare_octrees           opencv_version                  roslaunch                  rosparam        rqt_bag      selftest_example
convert_octree            opencv_visualisation            roslaunch-complete         rosrun          rqt_console  selftest_rostest
```

Output of `which -a python` :

```
/home/brads/anaconda3/envs/ros2/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`: "/usr/bin/python3"

Output of `env | grep "PYTHON"`

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.5
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/brads/anaconda3/envs/ros2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/brads/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: What OS are you on? What is the output of `which python` or `where python` (the former for Linux/macOS, the latter for Windows). If on Windows, are you using the Anaconda Prompt? If on Linux/macOS, what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I edited the question to provide that information

Comment: What are the contents of the `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin` directory? `ls -la /opt/ros/kinetic/bin` should do it

Comment: I gave it another edit. Thank you for helping

Comment: This is very strange. Can you add `which -a python` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Can you do `hash -r` and then the `python -c` command?

Comment: Looks like the same output

Comment: Do you have any [Python environment variables set](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)? I.e., check `env | grep "PYTHON"`

Comment: Edited the question to add. I was using virtualenv briefly before I started using conda if that affected anything

Comment: Try removing that `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` variable - if it is set in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` try removing it. You can also do `unset VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to remove it for a session.

Comment: I've also seen `PYTHONPATH` cause issues too, so perhaps test clearing that as well (although in this particular case, it seems to only involve the 2.7 paths, so may be irrelevant).

Comment: I unset both `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` and `PYTHONPATH` and the behavior is still the same

Comment: Thank you merv and darthbith for your help. I took another look at removing VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON all the way and that did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to be virtualenv_wrapper which I had installed prior to conda. I removed via `pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper` I also removed references to it in `~/.profile` and then relogged in