# Python version 2.7 despite conda 3.6 environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using Ubuntu 16 and conda 4.9.2. I created an environment with

```
$ conda create --name py36 python=3.6.2
```

The above python version is available at

```
$ conda search python
```

But the following gives wrong output.

```
$ conda activate py36
(py36) $ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

I tried to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195541/python-running-version-2-7-despite-in-a-conda-3-8-environment)

But there is no folder named 'bin' at

```
/anaconda3/envs/py36
```

I then tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134889/creating-a-python-2-7-conda-environment-sets-python-3-5) which suggests

```
$ pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

The error is:

```
ImportError: No module named typing
```

Then I tried to install typing

```
$ pip install typing
```

I get the same import error.

How to solve this and create environment with specified version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-login and try:

```
conda update conda
conda create -n py36 python=3.6.2 anaconda
conda activate py36
```

Also, check if conda updated your user .bashrc file with:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# Conda generated block of code
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

If you want the conda python, then try not to use any other python virtual solutions (uninstall them) - leave just the system defaults.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by last sentence? What are the other virtual solutions?